# How to create new series in Highcharts, using dynamically generated JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I am working in representing data in Highcharts. I have got a task like representing sales of every company for every year, where x axis has categories from jan to dec and y axis has data in which each year's data should be shown in different series, for example, if year is 2010, then jan to dec of 2010's data should be displayed as one series and remaining years.

For that I have googled all over the StackOverflow but I have not succeeded yet.

Here is my code:

```
$.post('./reportdata/salesbyyear.php', { reportid: value }, function(data) {

    //incoming data from php echo statement
    var year_data = data;

    //replacing all special characters with space, except :
    year_data = year_data.replace(/[()""/>{}<]/g, '');

    //replacing : with ,
    year_data = year_data.replace(/:/g, ',');

    //splitting the input data into array
    var total_data = new Array();
    total_data = year_data.split(',');

    //creted two new arrays and stroing alternate elements of previous array into two different arrays
    var month_data = new Array();
    var year_name = new Array();
    var y = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < total_data.length; i++) {
        month_data[y] = total_data[i];
        year_name[y] = total_data[i + 1];
        i++;
        y++;
    }
    series = [];
    series = generatedata(month_data);
    function generatedata(data_array) {

        // finding total number of arrays by divding the elements by 12
        //so that if I get 44 elements, the total arrays will be 4 , i.e each array 
        // has sequential 12 elements that represents 1 year (12 months)data
        var total = Math.ceil(data_array.length / 12);
        var values = [];
        var l = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            values[i] = [];
            for (j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                values[i][j] = parseFloat(data_array[l]);
                l++;
                //adding data to series and using this series in highcharts code
                series.push({
                    data: values[i]
                });
            }
        }
    }
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
            lineColor: 'orange'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Customer Details',
            style: {
                fontFamily: 'monospace',
                color: 'orange'
            }
        },
        xAxis: {                   
            categories:['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'],
            lineColor: 'orange',
            labels: {
                style: {
                    fontFamily: 'monospace',
                    color: 'orange'
                },
            },
        },
        series: [{
            data: series
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: How your data does it look like ?

Comment: Hello Sebastian, my input data from php to ajax is json and I am dividing the total elements into two arrays where each alternate elements go into two different arrays, here I am converting one of the arrays into floating point and trying to send them as different arrays into series with 12 elements each i.e 1 year of data for each array

Comment: Can you paste your json / input form ajax here?

Comment: helo Sebastian it is like {"30196.0456":"2010","1234.567":"2010"} , it is followed by all the 12 months of data and then again and then 2011, so on multiple years,Is it clear ?

Comment: The json needs to be constructed in the form { field: value } so it should be { "x": 2010, "y": 30196.0456 }